# Install many font on Android device

Tags: languages, fonts

I want to read and write Thai and Tibetan languages and also see real symbols for many other fonts instead of squares.

As you can see, replacing system fonts is not a good method, because in this case we need a font consisting of all the aforecited fonts.

iFont and similar programs also just replace system fonts, but I need to add new ones.

My Android version is 4.4.2.

Answer (score 1):

**Caveat:** The exact files and format vary between Android versions. In both Android O and P (at least on LineageOS), the correct file is `/etc/fonts.xml`, and it has a warning not to use it. As of writing, I don't have any devices on Q to test with. So **consider this answer historical** even if it's still useful.

**Warning as of [Android P's `fonts.xml`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/2aff67d492f17aaeb896806061dfa3b7e49f059d/data/fonts/fonts.xml) (see [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/data/fonts/fonts.xml) for possible updates):**

> ```
>     WARNING: Parsing of this file by third-party apps is not supported. The
>     file, and the font files it refers to, will be renamed and/or moved out
>     from their respective location in the next Android release, and/or the
>     format or syntax of the file may change significantly. If you parse this
>     file for information about system fonts, do it at your own risk. Your
>     application will almost certainly break with the next major Android
>     release.
> ```

Basically, **expect breaking changes** when updating Android.

**Original answer:**

Android does support custom fonts, but there's no user interface for it and you need root access. The basic steps are as follows:

0. Make backups in case something goes wrong. **Do not skip this step! It's very easy to get stuck in a "boot loop" after making the wrong changes with fonts.**
1. Enable USB debugging (so you can use `adb` on your computer to fix your Android device if something goes wrong).
2. Remount the `/system` partition as writable. Some file managers do this for you. Otherwise you'll need to enter `mount -o remount,rw /system` in a console on your phone or use `adb remount` from a computer via USB debugging mode.
3. Copy your custom fonts to `/system/fonts`.
4. Edit `/etc/system_fonts.xml` and/or `/etc/fallback_fonts.xml` to tell Android where to use the custom fonts. I don't know where to find the font names for `system_fonts.xml`, but adding your fonts to `fallback_fonts.xml` *should* "just work" for characters that aren't in the default system fonts.
5. Reboot the device and hope everything worked.

If your device gets stuck in a boot loop, then you can probably still use adb to revert or fix the changes. From experience, this consistently happens when directly replacing the system's `Roboto-Bold` font with a custom font that doesn't have as many characters. This is the reason for editing the xml files and adding new files instead of just replacing existing files.